# How is the negation operator a connective?

Tags: propositional-calculus

While going through a lot of notes online on propositional logic, I've come to the conclusion that people generally refer to the $\neg$ (negation) operator as a *connective*.

However, strictly speaking, I think that a connective is any operator that *connects* two propositions; and by that means the negation operator is **not a connective**.

So is it technically wrong to say that the negation operator is a connective or is it correct?

Comment: Yes; the negation sign is one of the [Logical connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Common_logical_connectives)

Comment: It is only nomenclature: call them "sentential operators".

Comment: Don't attach too much importance to the etymology of "connector". Negation is a "one-parameter" connector (sometimes called "unitary") whereas othes are with two parameters...

Answer (score 2):

While the etymology for "connective" does suggest two inputs, the term is used more broadly in this technical context: negation is considered a connective despite having a single input, and higer-arity connectives are also considered (see e.g. [here](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1131&context=rhumj)).

This happens quite frequently in (and outside as well) mathematics; ultimately, you just need to accept the standard usage, even if it's somewhat (or even [extremely](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011077)) odd.